# ACM - Audio Compression Manager

Tags: windows, audio

Can anyone explain how to use the Windows Audio Compression Manager (using VC++)? thanks
And what areas do i need to study first before I start..

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what Stu has said, you need to learn about the format of the WAVEFORMATEX structure for whatever compression types you want to work with. If you have WAV files, they will already contain a WAVEFORMATEX structure you can use directly, but if you want to use ACM to decompress say MP3 files, you will need to construct the WAVEFORMATEX yourself, which is often non-trivial (google is your friend).

Secondly, use of ACM is easier with constant bit rate compression as you know how much will come out given how much goes in, and you can convert entire blocks. With VBR you may need to deal with "leftovers" in source buffer.

Third, you need to realise that often conversions cannot be performed in a single step. All compressed formats will offer a decompression to PCM, but then you might need to perform a secondary conversion to get to the sample rate or bit rate you desire.

Comment: @Mark: Sorry, but I must say this is all quite useless - you just repeat theory from 'about acm' page in MSDN. In praxis, ACM is often used in audio/video scenarios, where audio data are split into chunks based on video frame rate, and it all gets complicated quite a lot even for people who are very familiar with WAVEFORMAT (who doesn't?). People usually know WAVEFORMAT structure if they have any praxis with sound in Windows, but it is still a long run from WAVEFORMAT to ACM. Maybe it would be easier to use ffmpeg library instead of rather undocumented ACM.

Answer (score 2):

Your first point of call should be the [relevant entries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms705349(VS.85).aspx) in MSDN, which explain ACM usage in great detail and provides sample code and tutorials.

It's actually a very easy API to use - you simply create a compression stream, specifying your required input and output formats, and then create source and destination buffers. You write your source data into your source buffers and give them to the ACM to process. The ACM will then return processed output buffers to a callback function that you provide.

Comment: I don't agree with the statement "[MSDN] explains ACM usage in great detail". There are actually just a few examples, almost no documentation on functions and macros. Many functions are "documented" by just a single sentence which doesn't help anyone. The same applies to Microsoft's video compression manager. If I compare the level of detail in the documentation to C runtime library or regular Windows API functions, it's shockingly different.

Answer (score 0):

MSDN has actually two branches explained (entry level)

First it explains how to write your own acm-driver (it explains how to write a program acting as codec);

Second it shows how to use the acm-drivers on your system.